# Is there a method to making ofstream save the file it creates?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, fstream, ofstream

The following is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string name;

int main()
{
    vector<string> authors {};
    cout << "Add Author Name:\n";
    cin >> name;

    authors.push_back(name);
    ofstream file;
    file.open("data\\authors.txt");
    file << name;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When I go to the directory that the file is set, there is no file with the authors name. Is there a way to get the file to save? I’m trying to program a sort of cataloguing program for a personal library, just an easy beginner project.

Comment: There's no error checking, but this code works if the `data` directory exists in the current directory.  It fails silently if `data` doesn't already exist.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of inititializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ofstream file; file.open("data\\authors.txt");` to `ofstream file("data\\authors.txt");`. And you don't need to call `file.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `if` statement around your code for the file to check if it actually opened correctly, otherwise you might not know, and in your case that's probably what happened.

```
ofstream file;
file.open("data\\authors.txt");

if (file.is_open()) // <-- add this
{
    file << name;
    file.close();
}
```

Also, in regard to your question about how to save when you do file I/O, meaning reading and writing, once you close your file then your changes are automatically saved because you wrote to the file.